# I want to store data in new index as per my key in php

Tags: php, arrays

I am having a data in array format with key and value what I want is from first key 0 to key 6 data I want to store in a new array with index 0 same for every other key 7 to 13 key with 1 index in new array in PHP

[image]

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Sounds like you might simply be looking for https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-chunk.php ?

Comment: it work with array chunk thanks.

Answer (score 0):

First, as suggested above, do not upload image of your code, just paste it here.

Just use [PHP array_chunk](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-chunk.php) function:

```
$pieces = array_chunk($my_array, 6);
```

Comment: [The fundamental goal of closing duplicate questions is to help people find the right answer by getting all of those answers in one place.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/duplicates#:~:text=The%20fundamental%20goal%20of%20closing%20duplicate%20questions%20is%20to%20help%20people%20find%20the%20right%20answer%20by%20getting%20all%20of%20those%20answers%20in%20one%20place.)

Answer (score 0):

you can use `array_chunk()` function

```
<?php
$a = ["a","a","a","a","a","a","a","a"];

$b = array_chunk($a, 7);

echo"<pre>";print_r($b);

?>
```

output be like:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => a
            [1] => a
            [2] => a
            [3] => a
            [4] => a
            [5] => a
            [6] => a
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => a
        )

)
```

Comment: [The fundamental goal of closing duplicate questions is to help people find the right answer by getting all of those answers in one place.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/duplicates#:~:text=The%20fundamental%20goal%20of%20closing%20duplicate%20questions%20is%20to%20help%20people%20find%20the%20right%20answer%20by%20getting%20all%20of%20those%20answers%20in%20one%20place.)